# Ternary Operator with Map NullPointerException Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap, integer, conditional-operator

The doubt here is if the key in the map is not present it returns null and here I am trying to get that in `Integer`.

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,Integer> hm =new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("abc",1);
    hm.put("xyz",1);
    System.out.println(hm.get("pqr"));
    Integer result = hm !=null ? hm.get("pqr") : 0;
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

If I split Ternary operator to `if-else` Like:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,Integer> hm =new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("abc",1);
        hm.put("xyz",1);
        System.out.println(hm.get("pqr"));
        Integer result;
        if ( hm != null){
          result = hm.get("pqr");
        } else
            result =0;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
null
null
```

What is going wrong in ternary operator?

Answer (score 3):

The type of the ternary conditional expression

```
hm !=null ? hm.get("pqr") : 0
```

is `int`, so `hm.get("pqr")` (whose value is `null`) is unboxed to `int`, which throws the `NullPointerException`.

To avoid it, you can write:

```
Integer result = hm !=null ? hm.get("pqr") : Integer.valueOf(0);
```

Now the type of the ternary conditional expression would be `Integer`, so there will be no attempt to unbox `hm.get("pqr")`, and no exception.

The logic that determines the type of the ternary conditional operator can be found in [15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) in `Table 15.25-A` and `Table 15.25-C`.

Comment: Alas, if only Java infers the type of expression using the left hand side of the `=` as well...

Comment: @Sweeper I suspect that doing so would have put the syntax parsing into a different difficulty class.

Comment: @Eran you said "hm.get("pqr") (whose value is null) is unboxed to int which throws the NullPointerException", and to avoid, you still neglect "hm.get("pqr") (whose value is null)" and instead you wrapped 0 into Integer which is already by itself an integer. what you did is probably not the answer and precisely you repeated the same thing done in his code. 
Also, it's Integer can take null since its not a primitive type! so I'm even surprise that he's getting NullPointerEception, if you check is second code you will understand why he should not have gotten the exception.

Comment: @Whales_Corps did you try to run the OP's code and my suggested correction before deciding it's wrong? If you did, you would get an exception for the OP's code and the exception will be avoided when using my suggestion. The value of `hm.get("pqr")` is `Integer` (since that the type of the value of the Map), so if I make sure that the type of the 3rd operand of the ternary conditional operator is also `Integer` (by using `Integer.of()`, the type of the expression will be `Integer`. When the 2nd operand is `Integer` and the 3rd is `int`, the type of the expression is `int`.

Comment: Yes, I did run the code and I did not get any Exception! perhaps version of Java matters? But I am sure you can assign a null value to a non primitive Datatype because they're basically an object and so an object can be null! getting NullPointer Exception is still mysterious to me after running it on my end and not getting it! that's my point. we can discuss this further with samples if you want. Also, apologies if I sounded rude. but note that you repeated the same code as the author of the question.

Comment: @Whales_Corps perhaps you tried the OP's second snippet instead of his first. Only the first snippet throws an exception.

Comment: @Whales_Corps `But I am sure you can assign a null value to a non primitive Datatype because they're basically an object and so an object can be null!` - what you are missing is that prior to the assignment to the Integer variable, since the type of the ternary expression is `int`, there occurs auto-unboxing which results in NullPointerException.

Comment: @Eran I tried the first! I'm sure.  HashMap<String,Integer> hm =new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("abc",1);
        hm.put("xyz",1);
         System.out.println(hm.get("pqr"));
        Integer result = hm !=null ? hm.get("pqr") : 0;
        System.out.println(result);

OUTPUT:
run:
null
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @Whales_Corps I just tried the code in your comment and it definitely throws NullPointerException. And I find it hard to believe that the behavior depends on the Java version.

Comment: @Whales_Corps which Java version are you using, BTW?

Comment: @Whales_Corps well, I'm using 1.8.0_162 but it shouldn't make a difference. If you read the tables in the JLS entry I linked to, you'll see that the OP's first snippet should throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: ait, over and out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no key `pqr` in the `HashMap`, so `hm.get("pqr")` returns `null`.

```
result = hm.get("pqr"); // result is null
```

From the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-)

> Returns: the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if
>   this map contains no mapping for the key

Answer (score 0):

There is no key pqr in the Map, so hm.get("pqr") returns null value.If you check with object it will return null.so you can change the object to key it will get success value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("abc", 1);
        hm.put("xyz", 1);
        System.out.println(hm.get("pqr"));    
        Integer result = hm.get("pqr") !=null ? hm.get("pqr") : 0;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

**Output :** 
null,
0

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If the key in the map is not present it returns null. You would further validate according to the key.

```
Integer result = hm !=null ? ((hm.get("pqr") != null ? hm.get("pqr"): 0)):0;
// result 0 or value
```